# How to set a global exclusive lock on whole table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

I need to know how to set a global exclusive lock on a specific table, so that it would work as a `lock` statement in C#. It should be explicitly set & unset from table.

Comment: What research have you done? What have you found that didn't fully meet your needs?

Comment: I researched locking modes of transaction, locking hints, but they don't fit. I need a temporary lock in order to generate a unique session key - first it would check for existing one and if true  will re-generate a random session key, then insert, and lock is released

Comment: That's a very common problem, which has been solved many times already. But I think you have searched for the wrong terms, you want to search for "SQL manually generating unique sequence number" or similar and you will find existing solutions.

Comment: Thanks. Never used SEQUENCE before, will try now

Comment: Its hard to search for that solution than I thought. First you should add the clarifications from your comment to the question. Then the duplicate I flagged should be able to be adapted to your situation, assuming you can't add a sequence that is.

Answer (score 3):

You can ALTER the table in a transaction to get an exclusive schema lock (Sch-M) on the table.  No other session will be able to read or modify the table.

Or you could use [sp_getapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get an exclusive lock on a named application lock.  This is like a named Mutex.

Comment: Can it be implemented in SQL transactions?

Comment: I don’t understand what you are asking.  Exclusive locks typically are held until the end of a transaction.